# How to move files containing, inside their title, strings from a txt file listing one string per line

Tags: linux, find, exec, mv

I need to move any file containing one of several strings in their titles from one directory to another. The  strings are in one file named brh.txt and are on top of each others, one per line. Here is what I have tried :

`for i in $(cat brh.txt); do find ./hehert -type f -iname '*$i*' -exec mv -t /home/bort/misc/ {} \+; done`

This runs for a while, but by the end of it, no new file appears in the target directory despite having loads of files that should match. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use single quotes `'*$i*'` for variable expansion, use double quotes `"*$i*"`. Also, it's better not to `$(cat brh.txt)` because if any filenames contained spaces they would be split. Instead, you can use `mapfile`

```
mapfile -t strings < brh.txt
```

And then use the strings array in a for loop

```
for i in "${strings[@]}"; do find ./hehert -type f -iname "*$i*" -exec mv -t /home/bort/misc/ {} \+; done
```

Or alternatively, just iterate through the lines in the file

```
while IFS= read -r string; do
    find ./hehert -type f -iname "*$string*" -exec mv -t /home/bort/misc/ {} \+
done < brh.txt
```